# How do I set different colours in geom_errorbarh depending on the value in R

Tags: r

I would like to set different colours for geom_errorbarh, like when *average_att* is over 1, the colour is red, and when it is lower than -1, the colour is blue. the colour is blue.

```
forestdata <- data.frame(city = c("HK6", "IS2", "CR5"), 
    average_att = c(0.752007081, -4.384720798, -0.66515768), 
    average_att_lower = c(-1.284027031, -6.088057285, -3.094599095), 
    average_att_upper = c(2.073787674, -2.637218695, 1.766942459))


ggplot(forestdata, aes(average_att, city))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax =average_att_upper, xmin = average_att_lower),size= 1,height = 0.1, colour = "cyan4") +
  geom_point(size=2,color = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(-6.5, 6.5))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0),color="darkgoldenrod2", size = 1,alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: structure(list(city = c("HK6", "IS2", "CR5"), average_att = c(0.752007081, 
-4.384720798, -0.66515768), average_att_lower = c(-1.284027031, 
-6.088057285, -3.094599095), average_att_upper = c(2.073787674, 
-2.637218695, 1.766942459)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less same as Quinten, just using factor and `scale_color_discrete` to keep things in order:

**I added a 4th row to the data:**

```
library(tidyverse)

forestdata %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(average_att > 1 ~ "red",
                           average_att < -1 ~ "blue",
                           TRUE ~ "cyan4")) %>% 
  mutate(color = factor(color, levels =  c("red", "cyan4", "blue"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(average_att, city, color = color))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax =average_att_upper, xmin = average_att_lower),size= 1,height = 0.1)+
  geom_point(size=2,color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(-6.5, 6.5))+
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = c("blue", "cyan4", "red")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0),color="darkgoldenrod2", size = 1,alpha=0.5)
```

```
forestdata <- structure(list(city = c("HK6", "IS2", "CR5", "blabla"), average_att = c(0.752007081, 
-4.384720798, -0.66515768, 3), average_att_lower = c(-1.284027031, 
-6.088057285, -3.094599095, 2), average_att_upper = c(2.073787674, 
-2.637218695, 1.766942459, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extra column that gives the colors using `case_when` depending on the conditions you mentioned. You can use the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
forestdata %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(average_att > 1 ~ "red",
                           average_att < -1 ~ "blue",
                           TRUE ~ "cyan4")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(average_att, city))+
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax =average_att_upper, xmin = average_att_lower, colour = color),size= 1,height = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(size=2,color = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits= c(-6.5, 6.5))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0),color="darkgoldenrod2", size = 1,alpha=0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red" = "red", "blue" = "blue", "cyan4" = "cyan4"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note: There is no value of "average_att" higher than 1, that's why no red.